# GIT SVN: fetching a recreated SVN branch without the wrong merge parent

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have the following situation with my upstream `svn` repository:

I created an `svn` branch and did some work on it which led to a really convoluted history. So I deleted it again, retaining the git commits, which allowed me to clean up the history quite nicely.

Once I had my patch series ready, I recloned my branch using `svn copy`, followed by a `git svn fetch`. The idea was, that I would then rebase the cleaned up history onto the new `svn` branch, so that I could easily publish it with `git svn dcommit`.

However, `git svn fetch` did not do what I expected. This is what I expected (fake `git log --oneline --decorate --graph` output):

```
* xxxxxxx (svn-branch)
* xxxxxxx (svn-parent-branch)
...
somewhere further down, unrelated to the above
* xxxxxxx (old-svn-branch-head)
```

But this is what I got:

```
* xxxxxxx (svn-branch)
|\
| * xxxxxxx (svn-parent-branch)
|
* xxxxxxx (old-svn-branch-head)
```

As you see, `git svn fetch` completely ignored the fact that the `svn` branch was deleted, mapping the recreating `svn` commit to a merge commit in `git`. Now, I wouldn't fuss about this, if this were of no consequence, but unfortunately, the wrong connection confuses `git`'s merge algorithms, creating bogus merge conflicts when rebasing across the new branch base commit.

So my question is: How can I entice `git svn fetch` to not link up the new branch base commit with the wrong parent, or somehow fix my git repo in a way that I retain the ability to publish my stuff with `git svn dcommit`? Of course, I can always delete the whole thing again, and create a new `svn` branch with a different name, but I was wondering whether a better solution exists.

Comment: What is the state of the `svn-branch`? Is it according to your expectations? Then I don't see why can't you simply do a rebase of you git-ed commits on top of the `svn-branch`. Do you see the full new history when saying `git rebase -i --onto svn-branch <gitted-history-start~1> <gitted-history> ` ?

Comment: @MykolaGurov The `svn` branch is ok. I deleted the old state with `svn rm`, then recreated the branch with `svn copy`. Both were pure `svn` operations, and both show exactly the expected result. Also, just as expected, `git diff svn-parent-branch svn-branch` produces no output. However, I get merge conflicts when rebasing from `svn-parent-branch` to `svn-branch` due to the bogus connections via `old-svn-branch-head`; the recursive merge strategy seems to compute a wrong merge base based on the wrong connections (it's a very active project). I know it's quite a peculiar situation :-(

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but you can define explicitly all the points for rebase, as I tried to demonstrate. Then given that the `svn-parent-branch` doesn't descend from `old-svn-branch-head` and neither your commits to rebase, I would not expect any issue. But then yes, you can always create a new branch with a different name and avoid this issue. git-svn does get nasty on non-continuous svn branch history.

Comment: @MykolaGurov While `svn-parent-branch` does not descend from `old-svn-branch-head`, both do descend from other common history. And I guess that is the reason for the merge conflicts. I have been able to do the rebase via a pair of `git format-patch` and `git am` without any conflicts, because that combination completely ignores the history of the involved commits. But a `git rebase` failed, even though it should have had the exact same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar situation and still couldn't find a way to turn off this behavior (`--no-follow-parent` turns off the whole branch tracking, which is not what I want).

I ended up fixing history with [`git replace --graft`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace.html). It creates a replacement commit and [keeps its children unchanged](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Replace). After the replace (ex. `git replace --graft svn-branch svn-parent-branch`) this is what you see:

```
* svn-branch
|
* svn-parent-branch
...
* old-svn-branch-head
```

You can still see the original commit with `gitk --all` option.

```
* svn-branch (replacement)
| 
| * svn-branch (original)
|/|
* |  svn-parent-branch
| |
| * old-svn-branch-head
...
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about `git replace`, yet. Looks like quite a hack, if you ask me 8-) Nevertheless, it seems to be a usable solution for the problem at hand.